# How to change Skype for Windows 10 notification color in Windows 10 tray

Tags: skype, skype-for-windows-10

I use the new Skype application that is a Windows 10 Store app.

I don't like to see the incoming messages as a preview, so I always relied on the orange blinking of the "old" skype indicating of the unread messages.

[image]

The *new Skype* displays an unnoticable number of the contacts that sent any message.

[image]

Somewhere I read a hint about having an orange or red number on the icon but couldn't find it.

Can I somehow make it more visible (changing the color or style) without enabling the preview of the messages at the notification area?

Comment: It sounds like you should use the desktop application version of Skype.  If there is no user interface to change the color of the notification, you won't be able to change the color of the notification, but i suggest you provide that feedback to Microsoft that it should be possible

Comment: The desktop version is all I use, and it only shows  the number of unread messages as well.  I'd love to get better control of Skype notices, and other programs' notices as well.  I know it's possible to make Skype's taskbar flash (again), since every time I reboot, any restored Explorer windows will flash and not allow me to auto-hide the taskbar, until I focus on each of these open windows.  Maybe we could make Skype's flash instead of Explorer's, which serves no known useful purpose. :)

Comment: @Ramhound : If default version is there they don't permit to install it as a desktop application. :(

Comment: Who is “they” exactly?  It certainly isn’t Microsoft.